How to Evaluate nested f-strings in Python?
I have an f-string that has placeholders which is not getting evaluated.  Sample code below shows the closest I am trying to achieve.
SourceSchema = 'myschema'
SourceTable = 'mytable'
SourceQuery = 'SELECT * FROM {SourceSchema}.{SourceTable}'
print(f"{SourceQuery}")

Result: It's evaluated as literal
SELECT * FROM {SourceSchema}.{SourceTable}

What I need is
SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable

Is there a simple way of achieving it?

f-strings are always evaluated in the place they are located in the code - that evaluation cannot be postponed.
So, this should work like you intend to:
SourceSchema = 'myschema'
SourceTable = 'mytable'
SourceQuery = f'SELECT * FROM {SourceSchema}.{SourceTable}'
print(f"{SourceQuery}")


Of course, this won´t help if you want your query-templates to be fetched from another function or file.
In that case, instead of query-strings, you have to resort to call a string's .format method, passing it the variables you want to use inside the string as parameters:
SourceSchema = 'myschema'
SourceTable = 'mytable'
# query template which can be retrieved dynamically:
SourceQuery = 'SELECT * FROM {SourceSchema}.{SourceTable}'
# rendering with the local variables:
final_query = SourceQuery.format(SourceSchema=SourceSchema, SourceTable=SourceTable)



Thanks. This is what AI tools recommended. Given I am reading SourceQuery from a DB table, I wanted to skip one additional step.
